# What tool have I to use to compile Sass into CSS on a Linux system?

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I am absolutly new in **Sass** and I have the following problem.

I am following a tutorial in which it is used **Scout** as **Sass** that compile my code in CSS.

The problem is that **Scout** is only fow Windows and Mac but I use Ubuntu Linux. What can I use instead **Scout** to do this taks?

Tnx

Comment: Try this one - http://koala-app.com/

Comment: We don't recommend tools here on SO, maybe you should try [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: libsass/sassc at http://libsass.org

Comment: `libsass` is a better option IMO as it doesnt have the ruby dependency. A list of wrappers to suit: http://sass-lang.com/libsass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install ruby via `apt-get`, [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/). Then you can install sass via

```
gem install sass
```

If you want to automatically compile your sass files whenever they change, you will probably want to use a build tool like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).